# write file js script in path project

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to write something in file js using asp.net mvc ..however, seem it not working

```
   new System.IO.StreamWriter("Assets/data.js", true))
         {
             file.WriteLine("xyz");
         }
```

it display

```
error at "Assets/data.js". Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\~\Assets\data.js'.
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you said using `ASP.NET MVC` you should use `@url.Content()` helper method to map your virtual path to absolute path like

```
   new System.IO.StreamWriter(url.Content("~/Assets/data.js", true))
         {
             file.WriteLine("xyz");
         }
```

In case you are using `ASP.NET` use `Server.MapPath()` which does the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Server.MapPath()` method to get the path to your location and use that.

```
var p = Server.MapPath("~/Assets/data.js");
using(var file= new System.IO.StreamWriter(p, true))
{
    file.WriteLine("xyz");
}
```

`Server.MapPath("~")` will give you the path to the root of the application where the code is executing. Since we specify further path location, you will get the proper path to the `Assets/data.js` under your app root.